# My Apache Camel Processor is Not Working

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to use an `Apache Camel` interface called a `Processor` and am running into some difficulties. I was expected the messages to 1) be sent to the ActiveMQ queues in the JBoss Fuse application server, 2) be processed by the Camel Processor, and then 3) be sent to a different Queue specified in the source-code. What happens now is that the SOP statements in main print and some error messages on Logging but nothing is sent to the queues from the program.

Here is my code:

```
/* create a Camel processor */ 

package foo;


import org.apache.camel.Processor; 
import org.apache.camel.Exchange; 
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;


public class MyOwnProcessor implements Processor { 


    //main 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        System.out.println("Starting main method in MyOwnProcessor.java");

        RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder() { 
            public void configure() { 
                from("QueueA").processRef("MyOwnProcessor").to("QueueB");
            }
        };

        System.out.println("main is done.");

    } //end main 

    public void process(Exchange exchange) { 
        System.out.println("Hello the process was executed.");

        String s = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        exchange.getIn().setBody("The body of the message is: " + s); 

    } //end process method 




} //end class
```

Here is the current output:

**Starting main method in MyOwnProcessor.java**

*SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.*

**main is done.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // create CamelContext
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    // connect to embedded ActiveMQ JMS broker
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            "tcp://localhost:61616");
    context.addComponent("jms",
            JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

    // add our route to the CamelContext
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            from("jms:queue:QueueA")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String s = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                    System.out.println("The body of the message is: " + s); 
                }
            }).to("jms:queue:QueueB");
        }
    });

    // start the route and let it do its work
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    // stop the CamelContext
    context.stop();
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this code to work after erasing the: `to("jms:queue:QueueB");` part. When I have this `to` part I receive this error: `Apr 16, 2015 12:51:32 PM org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer invokeErrorHandler
WARNING: Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V...` Any ideas why the `to` part is throwing the error?

Comment: If you change your code for the `to` part to `to("file:/Foo/Bar")` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a route isn't going to cause it to run -- you still need a running CamelContext, and it needs to be passed a message in order to get things started. Try getting this to work first, just using an anonymous inner class for your Processor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:source").process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    context.addRoutes(builder);

    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    context.start();
    template.sendBody("direct:source", "test");
}
```

Once that works, add a separate class that implements Processor and use that instead of the anonymous inner class.

Comment: Thank-you for the help @Dave. I tried this basically and received errors that the code could not find the routes. I am trying to connect to ActiveMQ Queue (amq) on JBoss Fuse. In another program I was doing this basically through this code `ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
  connectionFactory.setPassword("user");
  connectionFactory.setUserName("password");
  ` Any idea how to incorporate this into the code?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ActiveMQ myself, but it looks like it's fairly standard in the Camel world. Take a look at this page: http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html   -- It looks like you need to call context.addComponent() to set up your ActiveMQ queue.

Comment: That said, you might want to get the above code working first just to make sure you have the basic route working; then add in the ActiveMQ piece. I did run the above code locally and it was working for me.